# Select entries created after a date, which have big integer timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

The table has a `created_date` column which has big integer as time stamp values. One of the time stamp looks like this `1596007131121`. How can I query this?

```
select count(*) from user where created_date: date >='2020-08-30';
```

I need to query this.

Comment: If your question is tagged Postgres, why are you using SQL Server syntax?

Comment: its a  Postgres db, leme make an edit

Comment: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert that to a proper timestamp using the `to_timestamp()` function:

```
select *
from the_table
where to_timestamp(created_date/1000::bigint) >= date '2020-08-30';
```

But I would highly recommend to convert that column to a proper timestamp column.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select '1970-01-01'::timestamp + (created_date / 1000) * interval '1 second'
```

If you want this in a `where` clause, then use:

```
where created_date >= extract(epoch from '2020-08-30') * 1000
```

This has the nice feature that you can use an index.

Comment: i want do a query similar to ``select count(*) from user where created_date: date>='2020-08-30';``